# Update to Wix 3.14 from 3.11 get error MSB4181: The "MSBuild" task returned false but did not log an error

Tags: wix, wix3.11

After upgrade from Wix Toolset v3.11.2 to v3.14 i only get the following error.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets(1027,5): error MSB4181: The "MSBuild" task returned false but did not log an error.

when downgrade everything to Wix toolset 3.11.2 it works again.

As there are some security issues with 3.11 I like to update to 3.14.

I search the internet but I have not found any solutions.

Except for updating Wix I have update visual studio build tools 2022 to 17.9.2 at the same time.

Does somebody get the same behavior and did you manage to solve it and if how.

//Niklas

upgrade from Wix Toolset v3.11.2 to v3.14
expecting no error MSB4181

when downgrade everything to Wix toolset 3.11.2 it works again.